# How do I split a word into individual letters in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a number that I have converted into a string. I now want to assign each of the digits of this number to a new variable that I want to use later. How do I do it?

For example if

input = "98912817271"

How do I assign the one's digit, 1, to a variable 1 and so on?

I've tried searching for a solution but couldn't find any on StackOverflow.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python, words are already lists, this means, they already have positions asigned,
try: print input[0] and see
if you want to assign a variable the value of any position in your string, just select the position as if it was a list:
    foo = input[#]

Comment: _"words are already lists"_. I don't know about that. I tried `isinstance("123456789", list)` and it says `False`.

Comment: when you declare a string, it will automatically be a list of characters, this means: in the position 0 of the string you will have the first character of your string.

Comment: I'd give you an upvote but I do not have enough reputation to do so. I need at least 15 (I'll get +5 if you upvote the question)

Comment: A string is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=sequence#the-standard-type-hierarchy). A list is a sequence, so is a set. That's why `isinstance` returns `False` in @Kevin's example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def string_spliter(s):
    result = []
    for element in s:
        result.append(element)
    return result

print(string_spliter(string))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Often, a "code-only" answer can be made a lot clearer (and, thus, better) by adding a few words of explanation as to **why** the code presented works.